# Генерация двух одинаковых случайных строк независимо друг от друга

Tags: javascript

Необходимо сгенерировать две одинаковые случайные строки подряд независимо друг от друга. Вот как это должно выглядеть:

```
let obj = {
    string: случайная_строка,
    anotherOne: точно_такая_же_случайная_строка_как_выше
}

console.log(obj.string === obj.anotherOne); //true
```

Есть всего два очевидных условия:

1. нельзя объявлять глобальную переменную, чтобы потом вставить ее в оба свойства объекта `obj`;
2. при каждом вызове кода строки должны быть разными.

Создавать дополнительные функции разрешено, но если это возможно - обойтись без них. Для генерации строки предлагаю использовать простой генератор случайной строки, но не настаиваю:

```
Math.random().toString(32);
```

Интересны любые варианты. Задавайте вопросы, если нужно будет что-то уточнить.

Comment: _при каждом вызове кода строки должны быть разными._ при каждом вызове какого кода?

Comment: @Grundy при каждом вызове конкретно этого фрагмента кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function twoRandomStrings() {
  var previous = "";
  return function() {
    if (previous == "") {
      previous = Math.random().toString(32);
      return previous;
    } else {
      var result = previous;
      previous = ""
      return result;
    }
  };
}

var generator = twoRandomStrings();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(generator());
```

Comment: Идеально вписался в общий код проекта. Даже в голову бы не пришло использовать замыкания. Круто!

Answer (score 2):

```js
function * rndStr2() {
  while (true) {
    let s = Math.random().toString();
    yield s;
    yield s;
  }
}

let strGen = rndStr2();

function getObj() {
  return {rndStr : strGen.next().value, anotherRndStr : strGen.next().value}
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getObj()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getObj()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getObj()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getObj()));
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, к тому же впервые узнал про `function *`. Код также решает мою проблему, но галочку перекидывать уже не стану, но и репой не обижу))